# SQL Server ignores given format with CONVERT()

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, type-conversion

I believe this should be a fairly easy task but somehow it fails. I have dates stored in a text-field like `dd-mm-yyyy` and I'm converting them to DateTime-types using `CONVERT(datetime, [MyDateAsTextField], 105)`. But the output I''m getting is `yyyy-dd-mm 00:00:00.000` and I'm not sure why. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the output as a date/time in the correct format used for output.  Dates and times are stored in an internal format.  `convert()` translates values between strings and the internal format.

If you want the output in a different form, you can use `convert(varchar(), . . .)` to get the format you want.

More importantly, though, you should not store date/time values strings.  You should use the built-in types.  They offer much more functionality.

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick. I know it's better to use datetime-like fieldtypes but `1)` I didn't design the database, `2)` the design won't allow it, since the data is stored vertically (using a tablestructure like `Id | ParentId | Property | PropertyValue`). Where `PropertyValue` holds several types of data, depending on the `Property`.

Comment: @Ben - if you have to store them as text, you might at least want to consider storing them in format 126 (`yyyy-mm-ddThh:mi:ss.mmm`) since most systems are able to translate that back into a `DateTime` unambiguously (and often without needing to provide any additional information about the format)

Comment: Hi Damian, thanks for your suggestion. I'll try to convince the (outsourced) developers on this point. I agree it would make my life much easier ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using datatype as datetime use Char(10) or Varchar(10) and the date style like 105 for dd-mm-yy (Italian).

E.g.:
**CONVERT(Char(10), getdate(), 105)**

Output will be: **20-02-2015**